# Google map is not working in Angular App

Tags: angularjs

Below code of google map is not working in live Application using Angularjs.locally it is working.but when I upload to the live App it is not working there.how to solve this?

index.html

```
<div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:18px;">
                        <i class="icon ion-map"></i> &nbsp;
                        <a ng-click="launchGoogleMaps()">Location map</a>
                    </div>
```

app.js

```
$scope.launchGoogleMaps=function(){
        var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll="+$scope.temple.latitude+","+$scope.temple.longitude;
intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(url);
    }
```

Comment: errors in your console?

Comment: I got an error like Intel is not defined @TKHN

Comment: you will have to inject intel dependency ...in app.js

Comment: @TKHN how to inject intel dependency? I am new to angularjs.so the word  "intel dependency" is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.launchGoogleMaps=function(){
    var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll="+$scope.temple.latitude+","+$scope.temple.longitude;

    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",function(){
        intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(url);    
    },false);

}
```

This function only works inside event handlers. So you can’t just call it whenever you like to.
Make sure you have also added Intel XDK Device plugin in your app.

And last but not the least You should add this line in `config.xml` to let the app lunch any external url: `<access origin="*" />`

Ref: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: here I use this code and run, but when I click on the ngclick() nothing will happening there @Shivek Parmar

Comment: now there is no errors for installing Intel XDK Device plugin.but there is no change in map.and also when I install Intel XDK Device plugin I got an error like depreciate Intel XDK Device plugin @Shivek Parmar